# How can I get a list of pods using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, string, kubernetes, grep, kubectl

I tried the following but failed to get a list of all pods like these:

```
my-pod-1
my-pod-19
my-pod-24
```

etc.

```
kgp | grep -E my-pod-[0-9]+
kgp | grep -E my-pod-[0-9]
kgp | grep -i -E my-pod-[0-9]
kgp | grep -i -E "my-pod-[0-9]"
kgp | grep -i -E "^my-pod-[0-9]"
kgp | grep "^my-pod-[0-9]"
kgp | grep -v 'my-pod-[0-9]'

kgp == kubectl get pods
```

---

Also following kind Timor's suggestion I tried the following:

```
user@complt130:/mnt/c/Users/usert$ kubectl get pods | grep -E '^my-
pod-\d+$'
user@complt130:/mnt/c/Users/usert$ kubectl get pods | grep -F '^my-pod-\d+$'
user@complt130:/mnt/c/Users/usert$ kubectl get pods | grep -G '^my-pod-\d+$'
user@complt130:/mnt/c/Users/usert$ kubectl get pods | grep -e '^my-pod-\d+$'
user@complt130:/mnt/c/Users/usert$ kubectl get pods | grep -P '^my-pod-\d+$'
user@complt130:/mnt/c/Users/usert$ kubectl get pods | grep my-pod
my-pod-0                                                      1/1     Running     0          4d9h
my-pod-1                                                      1/1     Running     0          22h
my-pod-aggregator-cronjob-27946622-qnttj                      1/1     Running     0          16m
my-pod-manager-766d97676c-9hb5c                               1/1     Running     0          4d8h
```

---

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the options to the `kubectl` command to get the name column as the only output.

```
kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name
```

Then use a grep/sed to filter out what you do or do not want.

Comment: Thank you John. But still, how do I differ between my-pod-1 (and other digits) and my-pod-new (and other chars) ?

Comment: We are really getting into a regexp questions now! `grep -E my-pod-[0-9]+` should filter out only those pods with numbers at the end. You will have to provide some examples of what is and isn't working for you. For me - using Git Bash on windows - the previous grep command run on a file with lines `[my-pod-1,my-pod-19,my-pod-24,my-pod-new,my-pod-old]` returns just the ones ending in numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` like so:

```
kubectl get pods  | grep -P '^my-pod-\d+$'
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following option:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.

`^my-pod-\d+$` : matches the start of the line, followed by `my_pod-`, then 1 or more digits until the end of the line.

**SEE ALSO:**
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Comment: Thank you Timur. I added my tests according to your suggestion but it didn't work. I work on Ubuntu for whatever that matters. Thanks.

Comment: I don't inderstand why we need Perl regexes here.. We are simply using `^$\d`.. We can also use `-E`

Answer (score 1):

This one worked!!!

kubectl get pods | grep -P 'my-pod-[0-9]+'

Thank you all (and especially to @Timur who enlightened me about the Perl regexp option)